# Firefox blocks popup from localhost

Tags: javascript, firefox

This Meteor code tries to `print` but Firefox 46.0.1 says 'Firefox prevented this site from opening a pop-up window.
the file to print is coming for localhost:3000. and the `allow pop ups for localhost` is grayed out.
In the list under Allowed Sites - Pop-ups I have the following sites allowed:
http://localhost
http://localhost:3000

`about:preferences` does not allow me to access the Content tab which I read it has the settings for the blocking thing. When I click on it does not change from the General tab.

```
 let w = window.open();
 $(w.document.body).html(html);
 w.print();
```

Why is this problem and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: fix your Firefox settings - fix your addons?

Comment: @vol7ron where in settings? what addons? `about:preferences` does not allow me to access the content tab which I read it has the settings for the blocking thing. When I click on it, it keeps me at the General tab still.

Comment: That's the tab.  If you can't access it then that's out of the scope of this forum.  Sounds like you need to reinstall.  You may find what you need in about:config, but good luck. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/settings-for-web-content-pop-ups-fonts-languages?redirectlocale=en-US&as=u&redirectslug=Options+window+-+Content+panel&utm_source=inproduct#w_content-settings

Comment: @vol7ron finally I was able to open the Content tab. As I stated in the question, the `localhost` is in the allowed list.